# Fabric 2.5 howto use fabric.yaml configuration file

Tags: python, fabric

I'm trying to automatize some tasks with Fabric. 
My fabfile.py is:

```
from fabric import Connection, task
@task
def hostname(c):
    c.run('hostname')
```

And the cofiguration file is

```
host: www.example.com
```

Why hosts file is read but not used? Where is my error?

Answer (score 1):

`host` is not a [valid yml configuration file parameter](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.5/concepts/configuration.html#default-values).  The yml file can point to an ssh configuration file that can specify hosts, users, etc.